# Getting ConcurrentModifcationException even while iterating using iterator

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
//Cleans any stop words at the beginning of the sentence, returns the remaining
//sentence.
public static String cleanBeginning(String sentence, boolean skipEmpty)
{
    List<String> words = Common.getWords(sentence, skipEmpty);
    int i = 0;
    Iterator<String> iterator = words.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext() )
    {
        String word = iterator.next();
        if ( stopWords.contains( word.toLowerCase() ) )
        {
            words.remove(i);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String cleanedWord : words)
    {
        sb.append(cleanedWord ).append(" ");
    }

    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

On the line:
`String word = iterator.next();`

I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. Why is that? I thought `iterator.next()` was supposed to be a safe way to loop over an arraylist? Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Just iterating using an iterator isn't enough. You have to make your changes through it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove from the collection using the iterator, and you're not doing that.

Change:

```
words.remove(i);
```

to:

```
iterator.remove();
```

Comment: thanks! I always forget to do this.